# sublime text 3 auto duplicates input text

Tags: duplicates, sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-duplication

From some time (can't figure out from what change) I noticed that "Sublime Text 3" started duplicating classes and input in auto-mode with no reason at all. Sometimes it starts to write something on the beginning of document etc. It may be because of packages\extensions, I still can't figure out.

https://youtu.be/JXWbQWbjRko

I put all files on GitHub, will try to look for a reason of this bug. Was searching for it, but didn't find anything. Keyboard works fine, the touchpad was switched off.

https://github.com/Vimpil/SublimeText3_Settings

Comment: Since you have not changed to much it might be better to just [revert ST to a fresh state](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html) and stepwise reinstall the packages.

Comment: r-stein, good advice, i thinking the reason in LiveStyle extension. Will try it and will check the extensions conflict.

Comment: https://github.com/Vimpil/Images_stack_overflow/blob/master/LiveStyle%20log%20%F0%9F%94%8A%202016-08-10%2018-44-55.png?raw=true got this error log in LiveStyle google chrome addon. Trying to resolve this problem, i guess that was the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the "Emmet LiveStyle" extension duplicates text and have some bugs with input\output. There was no fixes for LiveStyle extension still and only way is to turn it off - if it works too buggy. I turned it off and everything works for me perfectly. There was the question with the same problem, but it has another title - [Identify duplicate styles css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036857/identify-duplicate-styles-css) - people just turned off the LiveStyle extension.

The best alternatives for "Emmet LiveStyle" are "Emmet" and "LiveReload" (https://github.com/alepez/LiveReload-sublimetext3 LiveReload)+browser extension/free guard-livereload OS extention http://livereload.com/; LivePage - additional chrome extension.

Comment: P.s. It seems the best desicion is to install LiveStyle and turn it on only when there are need to edit smth in browser with web tools. And in other time gulp livereload is almost simple to install and use. Here is tutorial https://youtu.be/6NozIUUnYTA